# JS - Argument with default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I need to create a function where I send custom arguments to it. 
I am trying to have arguments that have a default value it is undefined.

But I cannot get t right, the code I have always gives me the default argument. What am I doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uxdmby0y/1/)

```
<script>
  sn_test({
    type: "image",
    file: "test.jpg",
    breakingPoint: 100

  });
</script>
```

JS

```
function sn_test(args) {
  var options = {
    Type: args.type,
    File: args.file
  };

  var default_options = {
    breakingPoint: 2000
  };

  args = $.extend({}, default_options, args);

  $("#result1").html(options.Type);
  $("#result2").html(options.File);
  $("#result3").html(default_options.breakingPoint);
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/uxdmby0y/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

- Your 'options' object is using different case in the keys: `Type` is used, while `type` is being passed through.
- You are extending `default_options` with `args` and not `options` which you have initialised, rendering it kind of useless.
- you are using `default_options.breakPoint` instead of `options.breakPoint` for `#result3`.

It seems like there's just a bit of confusion in terms of your variables and what your assigning to them.

What you want is:

- `args` - these are the arguments passed through to the method (the options being passed through)
- `default_options` - an object containing default options.
- `options` - an object containing the merged options.

These all need to be matching case.

[Here's a fixed example](https://jsfiddle.net/6u9udL99/)

Edit: Also consider moving your `default_options` declaration outside of the function scope if possible, this will mean it's not being created on each call to the function, improving performance. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6u9udL99/1/).

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the content of `#result3` to `default_options.breakingPoint` instead of `args.breakingPoint`.

This should fix the problem:

```
$("#result3").html(args.breakingPoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed using:

```
var default_options = {
    breakingPoint: args.breakingPoint || 2000
  };
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uxdmby0y/3/)

Comment: Coupling the value of default_options.breakingPoint with the args object defeats the purpose of default_options, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

You are always using default_options.breakingPoint instead of the overridden value.  Try this:

```
var sn_test = (function () {
  var default_options = {
    breakingPoint: 2000
  };

  return function (args) {
    args = $.extend({}, default_options, args);
    $("#result1").html(args.type);
    $("#result2").html(args.file);
    $("#result3").html(args.breakingPoint);
  };
})();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uxdmby0y/4/